# Oracle: importing records from tab delimited text file to database using pl-sql

Tags: oracle

I have never worked with Oracle. This is the first time and the job is quite tricky. I have a text file with records delimited with tab. These records are to be imported into a database using pl-sql. I have searched online but the solutions suggests using SQL Loader utility. But the requirement is to do that using sql statements. No command line utility. Preferable the SP or UDF will take file path and database name as input parameters and it will import the records when executed. Is this possible? Can someone provide me sample sql statements or any link that explain this process step by step? Also note that there can be blank records in file. Thanks in advance.

Comment: too broad.  from raw data - the proper way is to use the SQL Loader tool as you have rejected. That is what is is built for.  If you want to roll your own, then you will need to construct the sql statements for yourself - maybe usea good text editor with a macro capability to construct the statements.  then feed that to sql plus.

Comment: Look at external tables.

Comment: As AHWNN says - external tables.  But if for some reason you really had to write a pure PL/SQL solution you could look at the UTL_FILE package: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/u_file.htm#BABGGEDF

Answer (score 1):

External Tables seems like the best approach.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/et_concepts.htm

UTL_FILE is possible but you would have to write the code to parse the tab delimited text etc.

Comment: +1 if you can use `UTL_FILE` you can use an external table (the only requirement is creating a directory)

Answer (score 0):

http://www.allroundautomations.nl/download/NewFeatures7.pdf

check on that file, easy to upload a csv file to a table