# Sql on CSV and Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I wanted to run sql command on a csv file in a class file, I came across [this project](http://csvjdbc.sourceforge.net/) and was able to successfully run the sqls on the csv, but I wanted to run a query which would fetch from csv and also from a oracle table, is there any way to achieve the same

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16524569/oracle-importing-records-from-tab-delimited-text-file-to-database-using-pl-sql

Comment: So the project you have found (which looks useful) is a jdbc driver. You don't say how you are accessing it - java? In theory, you should be able to define a second data source for the Oracle driver, and write a program to read from both data sources?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an external table that will be alimented by a csv file :

**Example of creating external table :**

- 1) create  directory MY_CSV as '/home/oracle/my_csv';   Note:
  /home/oracle/my_csv has to be physical location on disk.
- 2) grant read, write on directory MY_CSV to scott;
- 3) Put your csv file on /home/oracle/my_csv at OS level
- 4)

  ```
  create table my_ext_table
     (
       ENAME VARCHAR2(10),
       DNAME VARCHAR2(14),
       JOB VARCHAR2(9)
     )
     organization external
     (
       type ORACLE_LOADER
       default directory MY_DIR
       access parameters 
       (
         records delimited by newline
         fields terminated by "~"
       )
       location ('myfile.csv')
     )
     reject limit unlimited;
  ```

  The external tables feature is a complement to existing SQL*Loader functionality. It enables you to access data in external sources as if it were in a table in the database.

**Then join those two table (database & external)**

*The main drawback of external tables is that you can't create any index on such tables, so selecting data can be rather slow.*